# Ignore radio list in tr:nth-child(odd)

Tags: css, css-tables, radiobuttonlist

I have a form I've created in a table, and have used CSS to use a different background colour for all the odd rows of the table (works fine).  However it is also styling each row of a radio button list which I don't want to do.

How can I tell CSS to ignore the radio list ?

I tried to upload a picture but I don't have enough reputation !

Comment: Can you provide us the fiddle jsfiddle.net

Comment: Dont include a tag into your title if you dont have to [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Answer (score 1):

A simple try from my side.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) input:not([type=radio])
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnJ7D/2/

Comment: This works to an extent but I want to colour the table row not the input fields.  I cant do a JSFIDDLE of my exact code as it is an asp.net website and am using asp.net controls.  It looks like it is creating a separate table cell for each option in the radio list which is why it seems to be colouring each row of the radio list.

Comment: Ive managed to host the image which you can have a look at here http://www.avenir-telecom.co.uk/images/form-image.png

Comment: @JohnHalsey Do you want to do it using pure CSS? Can I use javascript/jquery for that?

Comment: Can you post rendered html code.this will helpful to understand what the root cause.